# How to show current date and time on the front of the pass

Tags: date, ios6, passbook

I use php to generate a pass. I try : `$date = date('m/d/Y H:i',time()); // Convert date to string` and pass's field: `"value": "'.$date.'"`
 , and I see the result as date is correct, but time isn't. How to solve this ?  This is the front of pass:
 [image: front of pass]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your timezone correctly.

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set ('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
$date = date('m/d/Y H:i',time());
```

Or, if you want to localise the date and have Passbook recognise it as a date string, use:

```
$date = date('c',time());
```

then in your pass.json:

```
"secondaryFields" : [
    { "label":"Register Date",
      "value":"' . $date '",
      "dateStyle":"PKDateStyleMedium",
      "timeStyle":"PKDateStyleMedium"
    }, // etc..
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! For this date&time, can I add '\n' between them? How to add '\n' ?

Comment: I want 2 lines as it's long !

Comment: You cannot a newlines except for backfields, Passbook does not allow it.  Some formats will wrap long strings but others won't.  Best thing to do would be to use two fields, a secondary field for `date` and an auxiliary field for `time`.  If they are the last fields, then the time will appear underneath the date.

Comment: If I localise the date, can I change from 4/24/13 to 24/04/13 ?

Comment: It all depends on how your phone is configured. Looks like Apple does not support Cambodia as a Region Format ( unless you are [Jailbroken](http://hiih123.wordpress.com/category/region-format-cambodia/) ) so try setting to Hong Kong, Malaysia, or Singapore instead

Comment: yes, you're right ! before I set region format as united states, but now when I change to Hong Kong, it shows 24/4/13 !